# opera overflow issue css/html

Tags: html, css, opera

I have a problem with my gradient. The gradient is not displaying wel in **opera**. What am I doing wrong? see jsfiddle for further code:)

http://jsfiddle.net/KtDTK/7/

```
<div class="product_1">   
  <div class="product_block">
    <div class="block-gradient">
</div>
  <div class="block-top">
    <div class="text">
  <h4>kenmerk header</h4>
  <div class="kenmerk">
    kenmerk
  </div>
</div>
  </div>
  <div class="block-mid">
    <div class="intro">
  Introduction
</div>
  </div>
  <div class="block-footer">
    <a class="meerinfo" href="/empty.php?p=meerinfo&menuID=1">info</a>
  </div>
</div>  
<div class="order">
  <p><a class="order_text" href="#">Bestellen</a></p>
</div>
</div>`
```

Comment: you said "Well", how is it displaying?

Comment: the top of the box somehow goes out of the border-radius. try to open the jsfiddle in your opera browser en see for yourself. **EDIT** the div block-gradient goes outside the box. is use overflow hidden to hide the rest, but in opera it is not working:s

Comment: There are less Opera users then IE users. I wouldn't bother to fix this, unless you really need to.

Answer (score 0):

Decrease height instead of using `margin-top: -43px;` in your `.block-gradient` div.

```
.block-gradient { 
border-radius: 253px 33% 304% 0;
height: 107px;
/*margin-top: -43px;*/
opacity: 0.4;
width: 204px;
z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: i changed it a little bit with your content. It is almost perfect now i only have the top right corner which still goes out of the box:)

Comment: Use this [link](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=opera+child+background+overlap+parents+border+radius&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) to read more about this issue(first 5 links to SO). It seems like it's opera's bug and there is no workaround for it.